# retrieving the default outlook email account using Redemption

Tags: email, outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

just trying to work my way around using Redemption; I've got the following code to retrieve the RDOAccounts (Email accounts) from the default Profile:

```
Profiles profiles = (Profiles)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ProfMan.Profiles"));
Profile defaultProfile = profiles.DefaultProfile;           
//open a RDOSession for this profile
RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
session.Logon(defaultProfile.Name);
RDOAccounts accounts = session.Accounts;
```

Where I'm stuck is trying to determine which of the RDOAccount objects is set as the default email account - there doesn't seem to be any property on the object that I can use to see whether it's the default or not.

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `RDOSession.Accounts` collection, in particular `RDOAccounts.GetOrder` method: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm

Comment: ah okay cool - so RDOAccounts.GetOrder's first account will be the default one?

Comment: GetOrder does not seem to work in Office 2013. I have tested it with two Office 365 accounts, changed Store order in Outlook, but Redemption always returned the same account.

Comment: What do you see in OutlookSpy (I am also its author) if you click the IOlkAccountManager button, go to the GetOrder tab and select CLSID_OlkStore?

Answer (score 0):

I think this works - but if anyone's got a more elegant solution I'd love to hear it!

```
RDOAccount defaultAccount = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Store.StoreAccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RDOSession.Accounts` collection, in particular `RDOAccounts.GetOrder` method.